# Eigenvalues of the matrix $A^{\ast} A$ with A being an invertible matrix $A \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $A \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ is an invertible matrix, show that the eigenvalues of $A^{\ast} A$ are all positive real numbers: $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^{+}_{0}$.

I think that if our matrix is $A^{\ast} A$ then all the elements are in the form $|\alpha|^{2}$. I also think that the eigenvalues of an hermitian matrix are all real numbers.

I thought about a generic matrix $A'_{2\times 2} \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$, $A = \begin{bmatrix}x_{1} & x_{2}\\ x_{3} & x_{4}\end{bmatrix}$ with $x_{1}, \cdots, x_{4}$ in the form $|\alpha|^{2}$ and I end up with a characteristic polynomial that looks like $\lambda^{2} - x_{1} \lambda - x_{4} \lambda - x_{2}x_{4} + x_{1}x_{4}$ and I see no motive for having $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^{+}_{0}$...

Comment: Note that $A^* A x = \lambda x$ implies $\lambda = \frac{x^* A^* A x}{x^* x} > 0$.

Comment: Never heard about Rayleigh quotient, but I'll have a look ... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a result by Sylvester that says a matrix is positive/negative definite if and only if it has positive/negative real eigenvalues. It also says a matrix is positive/negative semidefinite if and only if it has nonnegative/nonpositive real eigenvalues.

In your case take some vector $v$ and consider $v^*A^*Av$. Let's name the vector $w=Av$. Then $v^*A^*Av=(Av)^*Av=w^*w=\|w\|^2\ge0$, so we conclude $A^*A$ is positive semidefinite. Therefore every eigenvalue of $A^*A$ is nonnegative.

If $A$ is regular then $A^*A$ is too, since the existence of $A^{-1}$ implies the existence of $(A^*A)^{-1}=A^{-1}(A^*)^{-1}=A^{-1}(A^{-1})^*$. Then $A^*A$ can't have $0$ as an eigenvalue, since that would mean there is some nonzero vector $v$ such that $A^*Av=0$, which contradicts the fact that $A^*A$ is regular.

In consequence all eigenvalues of $A^*A$ are positive.